# How to import data to an existing worksheet and then overwrite the data on the second import in VBA?

Tags: excel, database, vba, import, text-files

My current workbook is made of a two worksheets: 1) Controls 2) Raw. The "Controls" allow me to press a number of buttons to test processes I am building. I am currently working on importing the data from a text file to the other Excel worksheet "Raw." I recorded a macro importing the text file to the Raw worksheet and got the code. I modified it slightly to create a dynamic file path for any user and commented out one line of code (caused continual errors and couldn't find a good explanation for a fix). I am running into an error I am struggling with (I am not a developer - just learning as I go) The error I get occurs when I try and run the macro from the controls worksheet and send the text file data to the raw worksheet. The notification says:

Run-Time Error '-2147024809 (80079957)': The destination range is not on the same worksheet that the Query table is being created on.

I understand the message (I am not running macro from the Raw worksheet) but I do not know how to fix the code to get it to run.

My second question is, if someone can help with the first problem, how will I have to alter the code, if at all, to have the data contained in "Raw" to be overwritten when I run the testimport macro again?

```
Sub TestImport()

Dim FPath As Variant

FPath = "TEXT;" & Environ("userprofile") & "\MyFilePath\File.txt"

MsgBox FPath

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    FPath _
    , Destination:=Range("Raw!$A$1"))
    '.CommandType = 0 (Error here has something to do with query table data type - no value will solve so comment out and program runs)
    .Name = "File"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 437
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileOtherDelimiter = "|"
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-360
Sheets("Raw").Select
```

End Sub

Comment: I'm not very familiar with what you are doing but until someone with better knowledge comes around I suggest that you look at this code. `    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=FPath, _
        Destination:=Range("Raw!$A$1"))` Try replacing "ActiveSheet" with `Worksheets("Raw")`. That might cure your first problem at least partly. The new data are being written to `Raw!$A$1`. I think this is wrong syntax. Please try `Worksheets("Raw").Range("A1")`. That specifies that data should be written from A1 down. That command should over-write anything previously existing in that space.

Comment: Thank you Variatus! Modifying to Worksheets("Raw") Allowed me to run the macro from my control worksheet with no issues. You were correct regarding the overwriting; however, I am concerned what will happen if less data is published on the second import. For example the first week there is 1000 lines of data, but the second week there is only 900. The macro will overwrite the first 900 lines but leave the remaining 100 from the first week correct? Any way to ensure old data is removed from the sheet entirely?

Comment: Before the code adds the query to the active document, insert one line of code like `Worksheets("Raw").UsedRange.ClearContents`. That would wipe everything off the sheet.